# Can I use a 100AH battery instead of a 74AH battery in my Passat 2.0TDI, 2012

Tags: battery

I want to use a 100AH battery instead of a 74 AH battery in my car

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a 100AH battery in place of the 74AH battery *as long as it fits* in the physical location and the post location is in the same orientation. Most batteries which have more energy store are physically bigger than their weaker brother. This is because to store more energy, you have to have more space (in most cases). Double check to ensure there's no issues there and you should be golden. Having more energy reserve will cause absolutely no issues with vehicle or the electronics of the vehicle.